# Select a specific column based on column's value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

my ms access table like this:

```
ID | Group | Detail(A) | Detail(B)
1  | A     | ABC       |
2  | A     | DEF       |
3  | B     |           | GHI
```

How can my access sql select Detail(A) as 'Details' when Group=A, Detail(B) as 'Details' when Group=B ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use immediate if, IIF.

```
 SELECT IIf(Group="A",DetailA,DetailB) As Detail 
 FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Remou's answer, the IIF is a good simple function, however if you are comparing multiple values, it could quickly grow to fit all the IIF's, as an alternative in a multi scenario or even for singles values if you wish you can use the Switch method:

```
SELECT Switch(Group="A", DetailA, Group="B", DetailB) AS Detail
FROM Table
```

Then you would simply keep adding e.g. Group="C", DetailC etc

Comment: I think that if you are going beyond say, Group D, you would be better with a look-up table.